# Cannot preview edits without giving a summary

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

When editing a post in the app, sometimes I want to preview how my changes alter the post **while making changes**.

However, when clicking the `Preview` button without having already summarized the changes I am making / possibly about to make, a tiny red bar at the top appears stating "Please enter an edit summary". But as I might not know in advance if I make all the changes I originally intended to make, or when in alike situations, I prefer to give my summary afterwards.

A quick fix is filling in *anything* at the edit summary, so I am able to preview, and in the end giving an accurate summary. This however seems a bit strange to me.

Wouldn't it be better if this check only would be performed when clicking the `Suggest` button, and not as well for the `Preview` button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

The problem is that previews are done using a the exact same method as submission, but with a `preview=true` flag that does all the check but prevents writing to the database.  Using the same solution as iOS, I'm going to use a placeholder string when submitting a preview.